# Why is $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ compact in $GL_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently reading "Ramanujan Complexes of type $\tilde{A}_d$" by Alexander Lubotzky. There he claims, (on page 273) that $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. I see that this is a subgroup and I proved, that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. But why is $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ compact in $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

I tried to embed $\mathbb{Q}_p$ continuously into $GL_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ s.t. the image of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then the image would also be compact.

I also tried to use the determinant, which should still be continuous here (it's a polynomial). $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a metric space, so it's a Hausdorff space and all points are closed. So $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the pre-image of it should be closed in $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Then I thought I could use a similar argument to prove that $\text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is compact in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. But this did not seem to work.

Can someone give me an argument for this?

Comment: The topology is the one given by the sup norm applied to the image of $x\to (x,x^{-1})\subset M_d(\Bbb{Q}_p)\times M_d(\Bbb{Q}_p) = \Bbb{Q}_p^{2 d^2}$. It is obvious that $GL_d(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ is closed in $\Bbb{Z}_p^{2d^2}$. It is compact because $\Bbb{Z}_p^{2d^2}$ is compact.

Comment: Why is it obvious that $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{2d^2}$?
Also, witch topology is given by this map and why?

Comment: No idea where you are stuck nor what you mean with which topology.

Comment: You said: "The topology is the one given by the sup norm applied to the image of $x \to (x,x^{-1})$". The topology of which space? And why is this the case? Maybe I'm missing a simple point here.
And what is the argument for "It is obvious that $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{2d^2}$."? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: The sup norm on $\Bbb{Q}_p^{2d^2}$ ie. $\| v\| =\sup_j |v_j|_p$. All the $|.|_p$-norms are equivalent on $\Bbb{Q}_p^{2d^2}$ this is the natural one.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. You can take the sup norm and want to use it to argue that $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{2d^2}$. Then we would be done(because of Tychonoff).

I do not yet see why it is closed, but i will think about it. Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of $\text{GL}_d(G)$?

Comment: What is $G$? $GL_d(K)$ are just the invertible $d$x$d$-matrices with entries in $K$(where $K$ is a field). Or equivalently the matrices with determinant not equal to $0$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb Z_p$ denote the field $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$?

Comment: No. It denotes the $p$-adic Integers.